# How do I update a pandas/numpy row with a xor of a next row into that same row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xor

Ok, the question is if there is a fast way with pandas or numpy to xor an array and update the next row with the results.

Basically I have a pandas data frame named 'ss' like so:

```
    rst  no1  no2  no3  no4  no5  no6  no7
0     1    6    2   15   14    9    5    1
1    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2     9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0


Use: ss = pd.read_clipboard()
to copy paste the dataframe into a variable use the above command
```

What I want to do is to update each 'no' column with a xor from the next 'rst' column such that each no row in is equal to ss.loc[1:, ['no1', 'no2', 'etc']) = [ss.loc[1, ('rst')] ^ ss.loc[0, [0, ['no1', 'no2', 'etc']) or something like that so the first step would create a dataframe like this:

```
    rst  no1  no2  no3  no4  no5  no6  no7
0     1    6    2   15   14    9    5    1
1    11   13    9    4    5    2   14   10
2     9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

which is basically ss.loc[1, ('rst')] which is 11 so 11 ^ np.array([ 6, 2, 15, 14, 9, 5, 1]) which the result is np.array([13, 9, 4, 5, 2, 14, 10]) which then I set to each no column in sequence as you can see above.

and the next step is to take ss.loc[2, ('rst')] which is 9 and do the next sequence:

    rst  no1  no2  no3  no4  no5  no6  no7
0     1    6    2   15   14    9    5    1
1    11   13    9    4    5    2   14   10
2     9    4    0   13   12   11    7    3
3    11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4     3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

so 9 ^ np.array([13, 9, 4, 5, 2, 14, 10])  which the result is
np.array([4, 0, 13, 12, 11 , 7, 3]) which then I set in each no column in sequence as you can see above.

My question is how do I do this with numpy or pandas in a fast/quick way, and can I do the without the use of any loops as I'm working with a data set of one million and looping is slow so I'm hoping there is a shortcut or better method of setting each 'no*' column with the xor of the next 'rst' row to the corresponding 'no' column in the same row as the 'rst' column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.bitwise_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html), once in its [`accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) variant on `rst`, then combined to the `no` columns:

```
rst = ss['rst'].to_numpy(copy=True)[:,None]
rst[0] = 0
no = ss.filter(like='no').iloc[0].to_numpy()

x = np.bitwise_xor(np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(rst, axis=0), no)

out = ss[['rst']].join(
       pd.DataFrame(x, index=ss.index, columns=list(ss.filter(like='no')))
      )
```

This works because XOR is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so `A^B^C` equals `(A^C)^B`. Here we fist accumulate the XOR on `rst` to then apply it on the first row for each intermediate.

Output:

```
   rst  no1  no2  no3  no4  no5  no6  no7
0    1    6    2   15   14    9    5    1
1   11   13    9    4    5    2   14   10
2    9    4    0   13   12   11    7    3
3   11   15   11    6    7    0   12    8
4    3   12    8    5    4    3   15   11
5   15    3    7   10   11   12    0    4
6    0    3    7   10   11   12    0    4
```